# Elastic beanstalk - separate environment configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two ELB environments, called:

- Test-env
- Test-dev

All pointing to one application called *Test*.

My ELB configuration under **.ebextensions/environment.config** is as follows:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: MODE
    value: 'dev'
  - option_name: BRIDGE_FEE
    value: '15'
  - option_name: ETH_RPC_URL_TEST
    value: 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/506787e430a7454d8c4f4ef77f3942e4'
  - option_name: ETH_RPC_URL_MAIN
    value: 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/506787e430a7454d8c4f4ef77f3942e4'
```

The options appear correctly under the target environment (env and dev), but I have multiple environments running the same application.

- How do I create specific configurations for each environment?
- If I have placeholder values on the *environment.config* file (sensitive data that is environment specific) will they get overwritten on each deploy? If so, how do I get them to stick.